# Is there a way/app to block outgoing international calls, without activating the network provider's International Call Barring?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calls

I 'accidentally' dial international numbers a lot - don't ask why, long story :). Is there an app that would restrict me from calling international numbers, or warn me before connecting the call?

I can put in a request for International Call Barring with my network provider, but that disables calling premium UK numbers as well (I'm with O2 in the UK). Plus I'd like to make the odd intentional overseas call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there seems to be a [range of apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=outgoing%20call%20blocker&c=apps) that may do what you are trying to accomplish.

here are a couple that look like they have potential.

- [Root Call Blocker Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=fahrbot.apps.rootcallblocker.pro&feature=search_result)
- [Call Guard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.incorporateapps.callblocker&feature=search_result)
- [Call Blocker Gold](https://market.android.com/details?id=blacknWhite.CallBlocker.Gold&feature=search_result)
- [Outgoing Call Blocker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.guardam.outgoingcallblocker&feature=search_result)

Comment: all the apps listed are outdated (removed from Play) now. Do you know any relevant for 2019?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ryan for listing the App. I was searching for a similar app for couple of days and I found the "Call Blocker Gold" works exactly what I needed.
Ace,
you can install the app.
there are 3 sections.
1) Bar incoming - leave it
2) Bar outgoing for the IDD you can add 2 rules
+*
00*
3) Never Bar outgoing . One rule for the local calls.
+65* (for singapore, as this is not an ISD. you can similarly put all the local patterns like in UK it could be +44*)

Other wise local calls with +will be also barred considering as ISD.