# Prevent outgoing international calls except when made through Google voice

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls, google-voice

Is there any way to prevent outgoing international calls except when made through Google voice, and without having to ask the mobile network carrier to block them?

I am the way of [Is there a way/app to block outgoing international calls, without activating the network provider's International Call Barring?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20286/12202) but I still want to go voice to be able to make international calls.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set up such configuration:

1. Go to **Outgoing calls** setting in GV preferences

[image: one]

2. Tick **International calls only** inside this menu

[image: one]